# Windows 8.1 Preview No sound on Macbook Pro Retina

Tags: boot-camp, windows-8.1

Anyone else tried the new Windows 8.1 Preview that do not have sound or is it just unlucky? I tried uninstalling the sound drivers and then reinstalling bootcamp several times, but nothing seems to help

**EDIT:** Sound is back if you uninstall the drivesr and install the drivers alone from (cirrus in the bootcamp folder alone, dont install all of bootcamp again)
Sometimes it also works just to uninstall the drivers, rebooting and letting windows handle it
Just be aware that the sound coming from the speakers are VERY tinny, headphone jack is fine though

Comment: It's a preview for a reason.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about preview release. Feel free to flag this for reopen it persists once WIn 8.1 hits RTM

Comment: To answer that question (and I don't think it's off-topic at all): 

For me it helped to "disable all enhancements" in the settings of the speakers audio output device

Answer (score 1):

As Sathya said, it's a preview, so there might be risks with installing it. It's not a finished product.

From [Windows 8.1 Preview: FAQ | Are there risks to installing Windows 8.1 preview?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq)

> Yes. Windows 8.1 Preview and Windows RT 8.1 Preview are stable and have been thoroughly tested, but aren't the finished product. Your PC could crash and you could lose important files. You should back up your data and you shouldn't test the preview on your primary home or business PC. You might also encounter problems like:

```
Software that doesn’t install or work correctly, including antivirus or security programs.

Printers, video cards, or other hardware that doesn’t work.

Difficulty accessing corporate or home networks.

Damage to some of your files.
```

> You should carefully balance the risks and rewards of trying out the preview before you install it.

What you could do, is provide feedback on your issue to Microsoft here: [Microsoft Community [Windows 8.1 Preview]](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr?auth=1)

Comment: I know that, but this dont help me, and maybe someone have fixed it with a hack